# My modal won't popup ; Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute `action` error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'd like to preface this question by saying I'm new to react and reactjs, but the documentation and stack overflow have been very helpful. 
This is my code:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

export class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "http://yourjavascript.com/722803554/addskills.js";
    script.async = true;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <style dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: "\n        input[type=submit] {\n            background-color: rgb(226, 17, 17);\n            border: none;\n            color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n            padding: 6px 6px;\n            text-decoration: none;\n            margin: 4px 2px;\n            cursor: pointer;\n        }\n\n        .dropdown-submenu {\n            position: relative;\n        }\n\n        .dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {\n            top: 0;\n            left: 100%;\n            margin-top: -1px;\n        }\n\n\n        .modal-content {\n            overflow-y: visible;\n            overflow: visible;\n        }\n    " }} />
        <meta charSet="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <button id="myBtn2" type="button" className="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">ADD
        SKILLS</button>
        <div id="myModal2" className="modal fade" role="dialog">
          <div className="modal-content">
            <div className="modal-header">
              <h4 className="modal-title">Add an aquirred skill below</h4>
            </div>
            <div className="modal-body">
              <h3>Aquried skills</h3>
              <p>
                please select an Skill which you are confident enoguh to display.
                Please not you will need to add one at a time inorder to properly add it to your profile.
            </p>
              <form action method="get">
                <input list="skill" name="skills" />
                <datalist id="skill">
                  <option value="other 3">
                  </option><option value="other 4">
                  </option><option value="other 5">
                  </option></datalist>
                <input type="submit" />
              </form>
            </div>
            <div className="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" className="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
                Close
            </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

that JS file is

```
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal2");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn2");


// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
// btn.onclick = function () {
//   modal.style.display = "block";
//}



// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function (event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

In my console I get the error message[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Y8Ov.png)
I didn't really change anything outside the app.js 
Essentially I'm trying to have a button activate a modal popup and within that modal have a pretty basic data list. Doing so in react is providing a challenge.

Comment: this is not the right way to do things. You are using React and again, you are using external scripts to achieve this. You can register event handlers inside react components like in componentDidMount, register this listener

Comment: You can use `reactstrap` component library

Comment: https://reactstrap.github.io/

Comment: See how you can use modals https://reactstrap.github.io/components/modals/